# Palindrome Number: what is wrong with my code?

Tags: numbers, palindrome

I am writing code in c++ to detect if an input number is a Palindrome Number, which means its reverse is the same as the origin. I have problems computing the reverse int.

e.g.

```
121 returns true;
123 returns false;
12321 returns true;
10 returns false;
```

I input 123 and the sum should be 321. However, my code keeps returning 386. I stepped into the function with xcode. Still, I have no idea why reverse += (3 * 10) + 2 turns to be 35 or why the final reverse number to be 386.

```
int origin = x;
int reverse = 0;

while (x != 0) {
    int digit = x % 10;
    reverse += ((reverse * 10) + digit);
    x /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> why `reverse += (3 * 10) + 2` turns to be 35

Because `+=` adds what is on the right to the existing value of what’s on the left. `(3 * 10) + 2` is 32, but `reverse` was *already* 3 and so you are adding your 32 to the existing 3, which is 35.

You don’t want to *add* to the value of `reverse`; you want to *replace* it.

Change

```
reverse += ((reverse * 10) + digit)
```

To

```
reverse = ((reverse * 10) + digit)
```